# ASP.Net MVC jQuery UI DatePicker Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm at my wits end trying to force this jQuery datepicker control to understand specific date formats. What the hell is going on here?

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield" })
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        showOn: "button"
    });
});
```

On page load

[image: On page load]

datepicker clicked, so far so good

[image: datepicker clicked]

date selected... what?

[image: date selected]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate):

- `dd` - day of month (two digit)
- `MM` - month name long
- `yy` - year (four digit)

So `dd/MM/yyyy` *should* produce that result.  (The day, the long month name, and the 4-digit year twice.)  To match your initially loaded format, you'd want this:

```
dd/mm/yy
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOn: "button"
    });
});
```

As noted in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate), the `yy` format specifies a 4 digit year. When you write `yyyy` you are basically telling it to render the year twice. Relating to the month, jQuery associates `MM` (capital letters) with the name of the month and `mm` with the corresponding digit form.

In conclusion, the date formats differ between .Net and jQueryUI.

Comment: Thank you! If I could accept two answers I would ;)