# datepicker return wrong dateformat(mm/dd/yyyy) at controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

in mvc application i have use datepicker and have code

```
 $("#StartDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dateonly: true,
        });

 $("#StartDate").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd/mm/yy');
```

on click event

```
function SearchFine() {
        var StartDate = $("#StartDate").val();
        var EndDate = $("#EndDate").val();

        var pathName = window.location.pathname;
        var virtualdir = pathName.split('/');
        var directory = "/" + virtualdir[1] + "/ManageLibrary/ManageReports/FineCollectionsReportByDate?StartDate=" + StartDate + "&&EndDate=" + EndDate;

        location.href = directory;
    }
```

but i am geting mm/dd/yyyy format

thanks .

Comment: The `dd/mm/yy` format by the jQuery datepicker **is** the `mm/dd/yyyy`"general" format. That means that jQuery sets the `yy` as the four digit year. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559112/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format/22559181#22559181).

Comment: And if Y2K taught us anything, it's that you really should use all 4 digits for the year!

Comment: @AndreiV please check i have use yy if i use yyyy it's show 2014 to 20142014

Comment: Maybe I'm not making myself understood, maybe I don't understand your problem. Where are you getting the date in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format? Is it in the browser or on the server? Your title sugests that you're getting it in the controller.

Comment: yes at controller (means server) i am using same pc at this time for both

Comment: @pramodmaurya http://www.rajeeshcv.com/post/details/31/jqueryui-datepicker-in-asp-net-mvc check this link

Comment: Then what I wrote in my first comment and in the answer of the linked question still stands. I'll sum it up, for convenience: jQuery date format and .Net date format are different. In jQuery you set `yy` for the 4 digit year and in .Net you set `yyyy`.

Comment: @HiralNayak@Andrei V :-                                            var StartDate = $("#StartDate").val();
            alert(StartDate);
           it's return wright value

Comment: @pramodmaurya you should try this

[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yy}")]

Comment: on click this link generated http://localhost/alms/ManageLibrary/ManageReports/FineCollectionsReportByDate?StartDate=03/11/2013&&EndDate=03/11/2014     that's wright but at controller it get day 11 month 3

Comment: why are you posting client side code if the client side values are correct?

Comment: @charlietfl without sending value how server know what date client chooses

Comment: by `posting` I meant displaying code in your question. You aren't sending a `post` to server anyway you are creating a GET request

Comment: yes that's wright but why i am getting wrong format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions for your problem are:

- Verify if the correct value is sent to the server by using for example Firebug.
- Have you set the right localisation in the web.config?
- Note that ASP MVC uses `InvariantUICulture` when you do a GET request, so 11/03/2010 will become November 3. You can test this by sending a date like 31/12/2010, the `DateTime` will be equal to `default(DateTime)` because it can't be parsed to mm/dd/yyyy. For a POST request, the localisation of the current thread is used to parse the date string.

  - Solution: send the date as string, and parse to `DateTime` in `ActionResult`.

Comment: InvariantUICulture how to solve this ...? i have added <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>

Comment: I'm afraid you cant fix the `InvariantUICulture`.. I also have no idea why MVC is implemented this way. But as a solution you can change the parameters of your `ActionResult` to `string` and do the parsing yourself.