# jQuery UI datepicker not working with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working with ASP.Net MVC with Jquery Date picker.

here is my model class

```
public class myViewModel
{
   public DateTime? FromDate {get;set;}
   public DateTime? ToDate {get;set;}
}
```

here is my View Class

```
@model testApp.myViewModel

@Html.TextBox("FromDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
@Html.TextBox("ToDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

and JQuery

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now the issue is whenever my page is load default date does not display in textbox instead "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" display in both textbox

So how can I display and bind current date value in my FromDate and ToDate textbox?

Thanks

Comment: any errors in the console? do you have jquery and jquery UI included on the page?

Comment: there is no error in console,also I have added Jquery and jqueryUI on the page

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22559270/526704

Comment: no I am not binding data from model.I am using just @Html.TextBox().I don't want to use @Html.TextBoxFor()

Comment: they're functionally the same. do you see how the date format is different than the one you're using? try using the one in that answer instead.

Comment: also if you're trying to bind to your `myViewModel`, you *should* be using `TextBoxFor`

Comment: Not working as answer mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68656/discussion-between-sandy-and-dleh).

Comment: Your using the overload of `@Html.Textbox()` where the second parameter is the `value` (to display). You may be confusing this with `@Html.TextBoxFor()` where the second parameter is the `format`

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            setDate : new Date()
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following using statements are included in your Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Change Model as follows

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

Your JQuery is

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "MM/dd/yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
});
</script>
```

And View Class is

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { id = "datepicker" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToFromDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { id = "datepicker" })
```